# View code in Managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, cti, visibility

We are using Avaya CTI Adapter Managed Package .
There are 4 classes in the package .

Is there a way I can see/access the code in the package ?

I want to see where the call details values are stored temporarily.

Comment: You cannot access the source code for a managed package, it is protected by Salesforce for obvious commercial reasons.

If you have a question regarding this then I suggest that you look at the support/documentation pages that Avaya provide, or contact their support desk with your query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [An Introduction to Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging):

> ### Implications of Managed Packages on Source Code
>
> If someone installs a managed package, they don't get access to all the source code of that package. For example, if the package installs an Apex class, they will not be able to view the source code of that Apex class. Here is a list of factors that should be considered:
>
> - Apex class source code is completely hidden; unless the Apex class is a `global` class in which case the `global` method signatures and variables are exposed.
> - The source of Visualforce pages is not hidden. However, the source cannot be edited.
> - The source of Visualforce Components is hidden.
> - Trigger source code is also hidden.
>
> Hence managed packages provide a strong form of IP protection