# How to know which API Calling?

Tags: integration, appexchange

How to know which API is calling & which operations are performed in my saleforce org whenever other Application(Java) hitting salesforce Org. I am able to know which application and how many Calls but I am unable to know which operations performed ?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot see the apex code coming from a manage package.

Check the namespace column when you open class list:

[image]

Comment: You cannot! Refer these posts - [An Introduction to Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging) and [ISV App Development](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/isv_app_development)

Comment: Also refer link by @tugce in your question

Comment: so am the admin of the org so is there any possibility to edit the source Code and i saw the link in that link  shown if unhide  apex code & methods  should global so how can make Global.
Thank You

Comment: nope, you cannot make changes/see code which comes from managed package.

Comment: Plz Let me Know  the solution for this....
So who developed this Code he can only Change the code ???

Thank u

Comment: Check this duplicate question [View code in Managed package](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136941/view-code-in-managed-package)